# Unite complex SVG files with paper.js

Tags: javascript, svg, paperjs

I'm trying to make a union of relatively complex SVG like [this](https://pastebin.com/eiJX7Viq) one. I want to unite the paths that make the "HELLO" letters with the big "A" letter behind. On Inkscape, I can do this by selecting all the paths and going to Path->Union, so the paths are converted from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Notice how the paths making the "HELLO" letters in the center are now united with the big "A" behind them. I want to achieve the same by using `paper.js`, as it's the best solution I could find to make boolean operations with SVG files without poligonizing them and because I can't do this with Inkscape CLI without GUI.

I create [this](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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) sketch in `paper.js` to load the SVG file and make a union between all the `CompoundPaths` and `Paths` hoping that would achieve the same effect, but, apparently it's not that simple, the resulting path from the sketch is:

```
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M-177.63334,-177.64819h755.85598v755.85598h-755.85598z" id="path32" fill="#000000" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal"/>
```

Which is almost an empty path! Is there ant know way to achieve this? I was thinking of any way to detect shapes as Inkscape does, I mean, on Inkscape you can indiviually select and manipulate each letter as a single shape, so If I can recognize every shape (or closed path?) I could make the union operation between them.

I'm a little lost about how to achieve this so any algorithms, tips, books, blogs, code or just about anything would be greatly appreaciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to solve it! I had to make sure to not `unite` paths that were used as `clipMask` AND making sure all paths were closed by using the `closePath()` method. The final code looks like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var scope = paper.setup(new paper.Size(200, 200))

var svg = `{put your svg string here}`;

paper.project.importSVG(svg, function(pathItem) {
    // Get Path and CompoundPath which are children from this item
    let paths = pathItem.getItems({
        className: 'Path'
    });
    let compoundPaths = pathItem.getItems({
        className: 'CompoundPath'
    });

    // Filter paths that are inside CompoundPaths
    paths = paths
        .filter((p) => !compoundPaths.some((cp) => cp.children.includes(p)))
        // Filter paths that are used as clipping paths
        .filter((p) => !p.clipMask);
    compoundPaths = compoundPaths.filter((c) => !c.clipMask);

    // Close all paths to ensure a correct union
    for (const path of compoundPaths.filter((c) => !c.closed)) {
        path.closePath();
    }
    for (const path of paths.filter((c) => !c.closed)) {
        path.closePath();
    }

    // If not paths or compound paths are available, return the same input SVG
    if (!paths.length && !compoundPaths.length) {
        debugger;
    }
    else {
        // Merge all the paths to build a single path
        let unitedItem = undefined;
        let compoundPathsStartIndex = 0;
        if (paths.length) {
            unitedItem = paths[0];
            for (let n = 1; n < paths.length; ++n) {
                const path = paths[n];
                unitedItem = unitedItem.unite(path);
            }
        } else {
            unitedItem = compoundPaths[0];
            compoundPathsStartIndex = 1;
        }

        for (let n = compoundPathsStartIndex; n < compoundPaths.length; ++n) {
            const path = compoundPaths[n];
            unitedItem = unitedItem.unite(path);
        }

        // Set fill color otherwise paths exported in the server (which uses node 8) end up without
        //  a filling color
        unitedItem.fillColor = new paper.Color(0, 0, 0);

        // Generate the merged SVG string and save it
        const outputPathString = unitedItem.exportSVG({
            asString: true,
            bounds: new paper.Rectangle(0, 0, pathItem.getBounds().width, pathItem.getBounds().height)
        });
        // let outputSvg = outputPathString;
        let outputSvg = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" width="${pathItem.getBounds().width}" height="${pathItem.getBounds().height}">`;
        outputSvg += outputPathString;
        outputSvg += '</svg>';
        
        console.log(outputSvg);
        debugger;
    }
});
```

The full code with the SVG string included is [here](https://pastebin.com/3zNBg8pv) as I exceed the maximum body length by including it in the answer.